# Как сделать так, чтобы объект в Unity падал быстрее?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-faq

Делаю проект в Unity, столкнулся с тем, что объект ОООЧЕНЬ медленно падает, то-есть после запуска проходит 2 секунды и он падает, как только происходит прыжок, игрок зависает и также медленно падает, что с этим можно сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Rigidbody есть настройка `Drag`. Чем больше значение, тем меньше скорость. Это что-то вроде сопротивления воздуха.

Так же там же есть `gravity Scale` который позволяет не менять настройки физики всей сцены

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а здесь можно почитать больше про прыжки: [https://gamedevbeginner.com/how-to-jump-in-unity-with-or-without-physics/#:~:text=One%20simple%20method%20of%20creating,of%20gravity%20on%20a%20Rigidbody](https://gamedevbeginner.com/how-to-jump-in-unity-with-or-without-physics/#:%7E:text=One%20simple%20method%20of%20creating,of%20gravity%20on%20a%20Rigidbody).

Answer (score 1):

В rigidbody можно увеличить массу - тогда быстрее будет падать

Comment: массу лучше выставлять такую какой она должна быть, а не больше. Потому что это повлияет на другие аспекты физических взаимодействий

Answer (score 0):

Edit —> Project Settings —> Physics/Physics2D —> Gravity
Вроде так, давно не пользовался

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: вобщем подействует, но заодно уменьшит высоту прижка